# Netsuite: EntityDeduplicationTask doesn't merge records with transactions

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a customer record with the same email, and when I try to run some merging script, it doesn't merge records with transactions. But when I run the script to customers with no transactions, the merging is successful with the other records deleted.

Does anyone here tried some work/issues?

Comment: I have done what I think you are describing and it worked as expected. If you share your code we will have an easier time helping.

Comment: You can't delete entitles with transactions. Use MERGE mode for those instead of DELETE.